# How to expand an abbreviated word onhover in html via css or javascript or even using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

For my portfolio website I am using my name as the logo and I thought why not be a bit more innovative and creative and instead of making my name use my initials and onmousehover have initials expand in a specific order.

For example If I used TTS as the logo and on hover have the TTS Logo expand to Text To Speech and when the mouse is not hovering have it revert to TTS. In my head I would like a typewriter effect where TTS is stationary and onhover have T**ext** T**o** S**peech** where the bold and the space are added when hovered. I tried googling this issue in a few different ways and was not able to find any results. If anyone has any suggestions on how I can solve this problem I would greatly appreciate the help. I have used both javascript, and jquery on my website so either would work for me. It is based off of a HTML5 and CSS with very minimal PHP code along with the javascript and jquery aspect. So I should be able to implement most solutions if anyone has any ideas.

Comment: Are the letters "TTS" next to each other, or is the space between the initials empty/preserved for the other letters to fit into? What html do you have? What CSS? Have you managed to make a start?

Comment: could you just use the html5 tag `abbr` like this? http://jsfiddle.net/1gwn59uz/ . Docs: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/abbr.html

Comment: alternative, a little css magic could just hide and show some 'hidden' internal elements and show on hover: http://jsfiddle.net/1gwn59uz/2/

Comment: @David well That was my question As of right now I do not really have any initials but I thought maybe I could have it next to each other and when it is hovered over it can expand.

Comment: @haxxton that looks like that works by any chance would there be any way to add like a typing animation to that expanding?

Comment: Anyways thanks for the help really appreciate it. Sadly I dont think I would be able to implement that into my site due to my initials having a period. Like this K.V.A. and wanting to expand that to Kyle V. Anderson. So the periods would be an issue. Anyways Thank you for the help it is really appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can do something like this

```css
span {
  display: inline;
}
span:after {
  width: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  transition: .2s linear;
}
span:nth-child(1):after {
  content: 'ext ';
}
span:nth-child(2):after {
  content: 'o ';
}
span:nth-child(3):after {
  content: 'peech ';
}
div:hover span:nth-child(1):after {
  width: 24px;
}
div:hover span:nth-child(2):after {
  width: 14px;
}
div:hover span:nth-child(3):after {
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>T</span>
  <span>T</span>
  <span>S</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Alright well that works but i have a few questions. First question, is there anyway to add a typing effect to the css? Second question, why specify the width if we can use auto that way it becomes responsive? Thirdly, is there anyway i can change the size of the text when it is being hovered?

Comment: Like for example is there anyway I could change it from  lets say 150% to 100% when it is being hovered and then back to 150% once its done? I tried doing it and it did not work well it did but only the contents changed in size not the entire thing. (When i say content I am referring to content: 'ext'; content: 'o'; content: 'peech';)